# Possible to update/refresh Flow QML component when item has been removed?

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a Flow layout where I add items dynamically on user actions. In the same way I remove these items on user actions. The Flow QML component seems to work as expected until an item is removed. The item itself is removed, but the space it occupied is just blank. My intuition tells me the graphical item itself got deleted, but the view is not updating when items are removed.

Is the dynamical deletion of child items outside the scope of the Flow Component? Is there any other layout that behaves equally? GridLayout seems to be the closest, but it does not automatically wrap child items when the layout is resized.

Is there any non-hack way to enable Flow to rearrange when child item is disabled? If not, and if GridLayout is my best shot, how to make it wrap its child items like Flow does?

The code below demonstrates what I want to achieve:

```
Item {
    id: root

    Flow {
        id: layout
        anchors.fill: parent

        Loader { id: loader }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        height: parent.height / 2
        width: parent.width
        onClicked: loader.source = "SomeQmlComponent.qml"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: parent.height / 2
        width: parent.width
        onClicked: loader.source = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you remove the item? Please provide your code...

Comment: @folibis: I currently use a Loader and operate on its source property. I know one is not supposed to delete a component that has been instantiated using a loader, but I don't think this is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Loader` inside `Flow`. In your case items are parented to `Loader` and not to `Flow` so you lose all advantage of that. In normal way items are added and removed w/o problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: element
        Rectangle {
            width: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 50
            height: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 50
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
        }
    }

    Flow {
        id: flow
        spacing: 2
        anchors.fill: parent
        add: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
        }
        move: add
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        property bool is_add: true
        interval: 300
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            if(timer.is_add) {
                element.createObject(flow);
                if(flow.children.length > 20) {
                    timer.is_add = false;
                }
            } else {
                var item = flow.children[0];
                item.destroy();
                if(flow.children.length <= 1) {
                    timer.is_add = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to insert the items at start instead of end with minor modifications? It seems like createObject() gives no such option.

Comment: It's possible. Since `Item.children` is just an array of items - `list<Item>` you can construct the list as you want as so reassign this array to `Item.children`

Comment: But I then have to assign it first as shown in your example, then rearrange right after? This could potentially mess up animations?

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm, and does not affect animations.

Answer (score 0):

@folibis - thanks for the answer, it helped me with a problem I was trying to solve which was to dynamically add elements and have them resize to the screen.  I took your example and made the rectangles fill the width and the height is filled by the rectangles with their height being even. So the shrink/expand with the number of rectangles.  I reduced it to 4 rectangles for simplicity and made it remove a rectangle at random.

```
      Component {
            id: element
            Rectangle {
                width: flow.width
                height: flow.height/flow.children.length
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
            }
        }

        Flow {
            id: flow
            spacing: 2
            anchors.fill: parent
            add: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutBack }
            }
            move: add
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            property bool is_add: true
            interval: 1000
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
                if(timer.is_add) {
                    element.createObject(flow);
                    if(flow.children.length > 3) {
                        timer.is_add = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(flow.children.length ));
                    console.log(i)
                    var item = flow.children[i];
                    item.destroy();
                    if(flow.children.length <= 1) {
                        timer.is_add = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```